# Pin TX0 -> 1 and RX0 <- 0 on ATMega2560 for USB serial communication

Tags: arduino, usb, atmega, atmel-studio

I am currently working on a project where I have to make my pc communicate with my ATMega2560 through the USB serial port. The ATMega2560 is the receiver.
I have been told that the pins `TX0 -> 1` and `RX0 <- 0` on the board are used for that:
[image]

I am coding in C++ in Atmel Studio. Can I just configure the UART to use RX0 and then it will work? Or do I need to do anything extra, which I don't do when I am using the other RX pins?

Comment: *" just configure the UART"* From that remark I suspect you have no experience with embedded programming. If you have then apologize and yes that is 'all' you have to do. If not, the subject is too long and complex to explain here. I suggest you search the internet for existing C++ code for driving the Arduino UART. I did not search but I am sure there are few hundred or thousand websites with that.

Comment: Pretty much any bare-metal-on-an-Arduino example, or for that matter the source of the Arduino bootloader itself would illustrate this.

Comment: this pins RX0/TX0 are connected to the 16u2 too (left on the photo) and the 16u2 handles the USB communication with the computer